# Core Data : Add relation object to existing object

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have following entities in my core data

- Message
- Department

where relationships are as below.

- Message hasDepartment (to one)
- Department hasMessage (to many)

Departments are already inserted in core data. When a new message arrives i insert it into core data and add Department relation but app crashes with following error.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'department' between objects in different contexts

following is my code snippet to set message object

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:context];

// find department object from core data.
Department *objDepartment = [self findDepartmentByDepartmentId:dict[kDepartmentId]];
// Create new message object
Message *objMessage = [[Message alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
    // *** Establish relation with department ***
    if(objDepartment != nil)
    {
        // app crashes here...
        [objMessage setDepartment:objDepartment];
    }
    [objMessage setLastUpdatedTime:[NSDate date]];
}

// *** Set other values in message object ***
```

Note : Everything is done using `Parent-Child` context in core-data.

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Comment: plz mention the error log

Comment: @Muneeba i have added error log.

Comment: are you sure u are using the same managedObjectcontext for both department and message? or you are using multiple managed object context?

Comment: same managedObjectcontext

Comment: finally found the reason after reading comments, i was fetching department on different context, modified the code so it fetch departments in same context and its working like charm. Thanks all folks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Department was fetched from Different context, you need to get department object from same context. Try if this works:

```
Department *objDepartment = [self findDepartmentByDepartmentId:dict[kDepartmentId]];

// Get department in in current context 
NSError *error = nil;
objDepartment = [context objectWithID:objDepartment.objectId error:&error]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch specific record for updating using NSFetchRequest

```
// find department object from core data.
Department *objDepartment = [self findDepartmentByDepartmentId:dict[kDepartmentId]];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest=[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Message"];
NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Message==%@",txtMessage]; // If required to fetch specific vehicle
fetchRequest.predicate=predicate;
Message *objMessage = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] lastObject];
if(objDepartment != nil)
{
   // app crashes here...
   [objMessage setDepartment:objDepartment];
}
[objMessage setLastUpdatedTime:[NSDate date]];
NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
     NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't Update: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
  }
  else{
        //updated successfully
}
```

//For inserting new record

```
Message *objMessage = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Hope it helps you...!

Comment: i am adding new `Message` object, while `Department` object is already stored.